# How to disable thunderbird notification when server is down

Tags: linux, email, thunderbird, notifications

**This is not a duplicate of [How to disable thunderbird notification](https://superuser.com/questions/87367/how-to-disable-thunderbird-notification)**

I know how to turn off the thunderbird notification when new message has arrived.

The question is, when there is no internet connection, and want to checkout e-mails for something (like log-in information or something for my cell phone), notification saying `there is no connection to gmail.com` etc... appears.

Is there anyway to get rid of this?

Comment: The offline notification seems to be inconsistent in Thunderbird 52, so upgrade to Thunderbird 60 and notice the difference. See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Thunderbird status is set to "offline" at startup, user will not see the offline notification. By default, the status is "online" at startup (Thunderbird 52 and older).

To manually set "offline" at startup, do the following.

1. In Thunderbird, go to **Preferences** from **Edit** in menu bar or hamburger menu (the right-most icon) in the toolbar.
2. Go to **Advanced** and **Network & Disk Space**.
3. Under **Offline**, click **Offline...** and "Offline Settings" window will appear.
4. Under "Manual state when starting up", select `offline` option.
5. Click **OK** to finish.

The offline notification will no longer appear at startup. Regardless of offline settings, when Thunderbird is already running on desktop, the offline notification does *not* seem to appear even when the offline is enabled or disabled from status bar or menu bar.

Previously, the offline notification seems to be inconsistent. Even when the status is "Automatically follow detected online state", user may still see offline notification (I experienced this).

With Thunderbird 60 and newer, no need to disable anything.

[image: Thunderbird Preferences - Advanced - Offline Settings]

By new default, the status is "Automatically follow detected online state" at startup. Unlike older releases, the behaviour is now consistent; user will *not* see any offline notification at startup, unless user has clicked on the "Inbox" folder.

Tested with Mozilla Thunderbird 52.6.0 and 60.2.1 on Linux.

Comment: This seems to be the case for at least `91.9.1` (and hopefully newer), I'm not sure about the versions younger than this, but for now it is fixed.